# C# - Console App - How To Read CLI option arguments

Tags: c#, console-application, command-line-arguments, .net-6.0, system.commandline

Using the `System.CommandLine v.2.0.0-beta3.22114.1` and `System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder v.2.0.0-beta3.22114.1`, I'm attempting to create a simple `get` command with a `--name` option.

The option is required. It expects an argument, and it will use it in the `Console.WriteLine` statement.

For the sake of organization, I am creating the commands in separate  class files and inherit the `Command` class.

```
public class GetCommand : Command
{
    public GetCommand()
        :base("get", "Filters events by name.")
    {
        var name = new Option("--name", "The name of the event you like to fetch.")
        {
            IsRequired = true,
        };

        AddOption(name);
        Handler = CommandHandler.Create((string name) => Console.WriteLine(name));

        
    }
}
```

While running the app, when I run the executable with the `get --name ali` command, option, and argument, I keep getting the following exception:
`Unrecognized command or argument 'ali'.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `new Option<string>` instead of `new Option`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For options that take an argument, you should use the generic `Option<T>`. Use the type of the argument as the type parameter:

```
new Option<string>(
    name: "--name", 
    description: "The name of the event you like to fetch."
) {
    IsRequired = true
}
```

Comment: Oh wow!! I'm such a noob. I completely forgot I had to pass in the type. That did it. Thank you.